# Netezza Parition by with excluding specific records

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, netezza

I have some data in web_event table of Netezza in this below format.

```
vstr_id  |  sessn_id  |  sessn_ts            | wbpg_nm 
V1       |  V1S1      |  02-02-2015 09:20:00 | /home/login
V1       |  V1S1      |  02-02-2015 09:22:00 | -1
V1       |  V1S1      |  02-02-2015 09:30:00 | /home/contacts
V1       |  V1S1      |  02-02-2015 09:32:00 | -1
V1       |  V1S1      |  02-02-2015 09:50:00 | /home/search
V1       |  V1S1      |  02-02-2015 09:55:00 | -1
V2       |  V2S1      |  02-02-2015 09:10:00 | /home
V2       |  V2S1      |  02-02-2015 09:15:00 | /home/apps
V2       |  V2S2      |  02-02-2015 09:20:00 | /home/news
V2       |  V2S2      |  02-02-2015 09:23:00 | /home/news/internal
```

This is my source table.

I am trying to use that web_event table and create another table like below.

I want the sessn_durtn table and time_on_pg table to be loaded like below.

1) time_on_page column : It is the time difference between the current page and next page load and the last page of the session can have 0 secs if there are no other events or page loads. It can be represented in minutes or seconds.

```
Insert into time_on_pg (select VSTR_ID,
           SESSN_ID,
           sessn_ts,
           WBPG_NM,
           ????? as time_on_page
           from web_event)

vstr_id  |  sessn_id  |  sessn_ts            | wbpg_nm              | wanted_time_on_page   | currently_known_time_on_page
V1       |  V1S1      |  02-02-2015 09:20:00 | /home/login          |   10mins              |   2mins
V1       |  V1S1      |  02-02-2015 09:22:00 | -1                   |                       |   8mins
V1       |  V1S1      |  02-02-2015 09:30:00 | /home/contacts       |   20mins              |   2mins
V1       |  V1S1      |  02-02-2015 09:32:00 | -1                   |                       |   18mins
V1       |  V1S1      |  02-02-2015 09:50:00 | /home/search         |   5mins               |   5mins
V1       |  V1S1      |  02-02-2015 09:55:00 | -1                   |                       |   

V2       |  V2S1      |  02-02-2015 09:10:00 | /home                |   5mins               |   5mins
V2       |  V2S1      |  02-02-2015 09:15:00 | /home/apps           |                       |

V2       |  V2S2      |  02-02-2015 09:20:00 | /home/news           |   3mins               |   3mins
V2       |  V2S2      |  02-02-2015 09:23:00 | /home/news/internal  |                       |
```

**How can we do this in Netezza or any SQL query?**

i have the logic to calculate the currently_known_time_on_page using

```
SELECT vstr_id,
   sessn_id,
   sessn_ts,
   wbpg_nm,
   ???????? AS wanted_time_on_page,
   extract(epoch from (lag(event_ts) over (partition by vstr_id, sessn_id order by event_ts DESC) - event_ts)) AS currently_known_time_on_page
   from web_event;
```

The main difference between wanted_time_on_page and currently_known_time_on_page is eliminating "-1" pages while calculating time difference except for last page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how large your dataset is and how much RAM you have available.  This query is doing it all in memory.  You could turn each individual CTE into temp tables for speed.

```
WITH CTE_SessionOrder AS (
SELECT
     sessn_id
    ,sessn_ts       
    ,wbpg_nm
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sessn_id ORDER BY sessn_ts DESC) AS RowNum  -- This is sorted Desc to get last row
FROM
    web_event
)
,CTE_KeepLastRow AS (
SELECT *
FROM
    CTE_SessionOrder
WHERE
    RowNum = 1
    AND wbpg_nm = '-1'
)
,CTE_OtherRows AS (
SELECT *
FROM
    CTE_SessionOrder
WHERE
    wbpg_nm != '-1'
)
,CTE_FilteredData AS (
SELECT sessn_id,sessn_ts,wbpg_nm FROM CTE_KeepLastRow
UNION
SELECT sessn_id,sessn_ts,wbpg_nm FROM CTE_OtherRows
)
,CTE_FilterOrderedData AS (
SELECT
     *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sessn_id ORDER BY sessn_ts) AS RowNum   -- Now Ordered Asc
FROM
    CTE_FilteredData
)
,CTE_FinalData AS (
SELECT
     D1.sessn_id
    ,D1.sessn_ts       
    ,D1.wbpg_nm
    ,DATEDIFF(mi,D1.sessn_ts,D2.sessn_ts) time_on_page
FROM
    CTE_FilterOrderedData D1
    LEFT JOIN CTE_FilterOrderedData D2
        ON  D1.sessn_id = D2.sessn_id
            AND D1.RowNum + 1 = D2.RowNum
UNION
SELECT
     sessn_id
    ,sessn_ts       
    ,wbpg_nm
    ,CAST(NULL AS INT) time_on_page
FROM
    CTE_SessionOrder
WHERE
    RowNum != 1
    AND wbpg_nm = '-1'
)
SELECT *
FROM
    CTE_FinalData
```

Comment: Arleigh the result set you provided only kept 1 '-1' result in your answer there are 3 in his result set and starting table

Comment: Did not realize you wanted that as well.  Updated code to include it.  Thanks.

Comment: I was trying to figure out why the crazy long post then I realized I wasn't picking up the last -1 and I was missing that in the OUTER APPLY, I will tweak the outer apply but I did just put together a CTE that you might want to take a look at using 2 row numbers 2 self references and tweaking the PARTITION BY in your ROW_NUMBER functions can help you get to your desired result a little faster.

Comment: Is your solution a MSSQL dialect?  The CTEs will work fine in Netezza, but DATEDIFF would have to be ditched in favor of AGE() or math on extraction of epoch.  Also, there's nothing here that would force this to be in-memory for Netezza.  Your SQL is nicely legible to me, and that's a plus!

Comment: @ScottMcG  Yes it is in MSSQL, tested in SQL Server 2012.  I am not familiar with Netezza.  I just thought Netezza was the source system that created the data set.  I did not know that it had its own syntax.  I will keep that in mind.

Comment: I think if you switch out DATEDIFF with this it would work as intended:  (extract(epoch from D2.sessn_ts) - extract(epoch from D1.sessn_ts)) time_on_page

Comment: Thank you for taking time, this helps.

Comment: Hi Reyna is there a way to run this as an UPDATE to update the web_event table with this timeonpage for each page load?

Comment: Yes, first have to add an INT column to your web_event tables, I am assuming it would be called "time_on_page".  Then rather than `SELECT * FROM CTE_FinalData` as your final statement you would use the code below.  It joins in three places as you really have no primary key for your table, so to be exact it has to join on all three fields. `UPDATE web_event SET time_on_page = CTE_FinalData.time_on_page
FROM
 web_event
    JOIN CTE_FinalData
  ON web_event.sessn_id = CTE_FinalData.sessn_id
   AND web_event.sessn_ts = CTE_FinalData.sessn_ts
   AND web_event.wbpg_nm = CTE_FinalData.wbpg_nm`

Answer (score 1):

I think event_ts is the same as sessn_ts ????  Anyway here is a query that should work for you it uses the `OUTER APPLY` technique to lookup results in the table that are after `(> sessn_ts)` are not web page `-1`, and then get's the top result ascending order.

Just change the table name to your table.

Here is a solution that primarily is using an `outer apply` but also using a common table expression (`cte`) to set the time for the last `'-1'` needed.

```
;WITH cteMaxNeg1 AS (
    SELECT
       sessn_id
       ,MaxNeg1SessnTs = MAX(CASE WHEN we.webpg_nm = '-1' THEN we.sessn_ts ELSE NULL END)
       ,MaxPageSessnTs = MAX(CASE WHEN we.webpg_nm <> '-1' THEN we.sessn_ts ELSE NULL END)
    FROM
       @WebEvents we
    GROUP BY
       sessn_id
)

SELECT
    we.*
    ,currently_known_time_on_page = ISNULL(LAG(we.sessn_ts) over (partition by we.vstr_id, we.sessn_id order by we.sessn_ts DESC) - we.sessn_ts,CAST(0 AS DATETIME))
    ,WantedTimeOnPage = CASE
       WHEN we.sessn_ts = m.MaxPageSessnTs AND we.webpg_nm <> '-1' THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,we.sessn_ts,m.MaxNeg1SessnTs)
       WHEN we.webpg_nm <> '-1' THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,we.sessn_ts,o.sessn_ts)
       ELSE NULL
    END
FROM
    @WebEvents we
    LEFT JOIN cteMaxNeg1 m
    ON we.sessn_id = m.sessn_id
    OUTER APPLY (
       SELECT TOP 1sessn_ts
       FROM
          @WebEvents i
       WHERE
          i.webpg_nm <> '-1'
          AND i.sessn_id = we.sessn_id
          AND i.sessn_ts > we.sessn_ts

       ORDER BY
          i.sessn_ts ASC

    ) o
ORDER BY
    we.sessn_id
    ,we.sessn_ts
```

Here is a solution just using CTE and window function

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sessn_id, IIF(webpg_nm = '-1',0,1) ORDER BY sessn_ts)
       ,LastNeg1RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sessn_id, IIF(webpg_nm = '-1',0,1) ORDER BY sessn_ts DESC)
    FROM
       @WebEvents
)

SELECT
    c1.*
    ,WantedTimeOnPage = CASE
       WHEN c1.LastNeg1RowNum = 1 AND c1.webpg_nm <> '-1' THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,c1.sessn_ts,c3.sessn_ts)
       WHEN c1.webpg_nm <> '-1' THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,c1.sessn_ts,c2.sessn_ts)
       ELSE NULL
    END
FROM
    cte c1
    LEFT JOIN cte c2
    ON c1.sessn_id = c2.sessn_id
    AND (c1.RowNum + 1) = c2.RowNum
    AND c2.webpg_nm <> '-1'
    LEFT JOIN cte c3
    ON c1.sessn_id = c3.sessn_id
    AND c3.LastNeg1RowNum = 1 
    AND c3.webpg_nm = '-1'
ORDER BY
    c1.sessn_id
    ,c1.sessn_ts
```

Test Data I used from you:

```
DECLARE @WebEvents AS TABLE (vstr_id CHAR(2), sessn_id CHAR(5), sessn_ts DATETIME, webpg_nm VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @WebEvents (vstr_id, sessn_id, sessn_ts, webpg_nm)
VALUES
('V1','V1S1','02-02-2015 09:20:00','/home/login')
,('V1','V1S1','02-02-2015 09:22:00','-1')
,('V1','V1S1','02-02-2015 09:30:00','/home/contacts')
,('V1','V1S1','02-02-2015 09:32:00','-1')
,('V1','V1S1','02-02-2015 09:50:00','/home/search')
,('V1','V1S1','02-02-2015 09:55:00','-1')
,('V2','V2S1','02-02-2015 09:10:00','/home')
,('V2','V2S1','02-02-2015 09:15:00','/home/apps')
,('V2','V2S2','02-02-2015 09:20:00','/home/news')
,('V2','V2S2','02-02-2015 09:23:00','/home/news/internal')
```

Comment: Thank you matt for taking time this helps.